# Drupal : add a dynamic link in navigation bar

Tags: php, module, drupal-7, hook

I have Drupal 7 and want to add a link "Login/Log out" in Navigation bar if the user is logged !

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in drupal 'user_is_logged_in'. You can use that.

Comment: i user another database (this is not the database drupal)

Answer (score 0):

I did that :

`if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
    $add_menu_navigation=TRUE;
  else
    $add_menu_navigation=FALSE;

```
    $items['deconnexion'] = array(
        'title' => 'deconnexion',
        'page callback' => 'deconnexion',
        'access callback' => $add_menu_navigation,
    );`
```

but we must empty the cache for drupal that the link is lost / displays !!!